# PHP object operator is number

Tags: php, object

My code gets some data from an API which comes back like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [http_response_body] => stdClass Object
        (
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [tags] => Array
                                (
                                )
```

I am trying to display the data such as [tags] and I am using

```
print_r($d->http_response_body->items);
```

Which works fine, until I want to get the array item called [0].  The code doesnt like:

```
print_r($d->http_response_body->items->0);
```

How can I get to accept the 0 after the items-> bit.  I've tried all sorts of stuff such as '0'  {'0'}  [0] and nothing works.

Thanks

Comment: It should be something like `print_r($d->http_response_body->items[0]->tags);`

Comment: that doesnt work unfortunately. just displays everything at the [items] level